# How to use F# exponentiation operator (**) in prefix notation?

Tags: f#

With most operators in F# I can use prefix or infix notation, for example:

```
let x = a + b
```

is equivalent to

```
let x = (+) a b
```

This does not work for the exponentation operator ** however, because the parenthesised version is treated as a comment. That is, (*this is a comment*) is F# syntax for a comment, so (**) is treated as an empty comment.

```
let x = a ** b   // a raised to b

let x = (**) a b // empty comment, followed by function a applied to b
```

Is there an escape character I can use or is this simply a strange quirk of the language?

Comment: Try `( ** )` instead.

Comment: @kvb I'm not sure how to extend this to the required number of characters, but you should post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using spaces between the parentheses, as pointed by [kvb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82959/kvb) in the comments:

```
let x = ( ** ) a b
```